# Sensitive Information Disclosure via plist on iOS, does this affect security at all?

Tags: appsec, mobile, ios

The security team has found sensitive information which is disclosed in `info.plist`, API keys were also exposed.  `Fabric` is being used and Fabric API key is the way to authenticate the users or their clients for all their services.

Also according to security team, Token was stored inside the plist file and this can be dangerous because users with jailbroken iphones or who’ve backed up their mobiles are exposed.

But when this was escalated to the dev team, they came up with:

```
This is the suggested integration from Fabric - Fabric provides a plugin to integrate with their SDK. Also, this api key is bound with our app package and the SDK is only associated with the crashes and not any sensitive information.
```

Tokens were also disclosed (push tokens), e.g.

[image]

But to this the developer says:

```
This is not an API key, just a token to suggest that a push notification was received on the device.
```

Basically, the bottom-line is they would deny any information that is being disclosed isn't sensitive enough for them and should be that was Fabric docs [integrates](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/integration.html) the API the same way.

So question is, to be very clear and transparent to the dev team, how could this be presented the right way and does exposure of API Keys in context of plist files in iOS is a security concern or I had been wrong here?

EDIT: I've found one [use case](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52863/is-google-api-key-a-sensitive-information-that-needs-to-be-protected) here but this has to do with Google API Keys. Also it's for Android.

Comment: API keys can always be disclosed - the best you can do is obfuscate them, but a dedicated attacker will always find them out given enough time and effort. However in a correctly designed app, the API token alone shouldn't give access to any confidential data.

Comment: In context of the questions, the exposed tokens were app push notifications tokens in Fabric.